# Arbuh mayoys viesray (410) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

Every number in the Torah is special

It's known that the first temple stood for 410 years, but can any other significance of the number 410 be found in the Torah?

Blessings and success

Comment: משכן has the numerical value of 410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Ezra 1:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.1.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) where it list the inventory provided to Sheshbazzar the prince of Yehuda:

> כְּפוֹרֵ֤י זָהָב֙ שְׁלֹשִׁ֔ים **כְּפ֤וֹרֵי כֶ֙סֶף֙ מִשְׁנִ֔ים אַרְבַּ֥ע מֵא֖וֹת וַעֲשָׂרָ֑ה** כֵּלִ֥ים אֲחֵרִ֖ים אָֽלֶף׃ (ס)
>
> 30 gold bowls, **410 silver double bowls**, 1,000 other vessels;

Comment: Interesting.....